# Python `bin` negative integers

Tags: python, hash, binary, built-in

I tried to repeat Brandon Rhodes' Pycon2010 talk [The mighty dictionary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fYlnfvKVDoM) and on noticed I couldn't use the `bin` built-in of python to calculate the least significant bits of a hash:

```
>>> bin(hash("ftp"))[-3:]
'111'
```

Which according to the talk should be `001`.

After a bit of digging I found that I had to use this custom `bits` function like Brandon:

```
>>> def bits(integer):
       return "".join(str(x) for x in [1&(integer>>i) for i in range(32)[::-1]])

>>> bits(hash("ftp"))[-3:]
'001'
```

Apparently because the `bin` built-in returns bits as binary strings with a sign:

```
>>> bits(-100)
'11111111111111111111111110011100'  # two-complement representation preceded by 1s
>>> bin(-100)
'-0b1100100'  # signed magnitude representation
```

Why is this so? Is there a particular reason for not returning the [two-complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) of a negative integer in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python integers have arbitrary precision and they don't have a fixed size: a 2-complement representation of -1 would require an infinite sequence of `1`s.